# Div doesn't loose hover state if parent isn't hovered

Tags: javascript, html, css, visible

If you hover above the second, third or forth item the hidden text shows up on the left side.

If you move your cursor to the hidden text, the hidden text will hide again.

But i want that you can hover over the second item, move your cursor to the "hide" and e.g. click on it. Is this possible in CSS or JS?

The HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="item">item
       <div class="hide">hide</div>
    </div>
   <div class="item">item <div class="hide">hide</div></div>
   <div class="item">item <div class="hide">hide</div></div>
   <div class="item">item <div class="hide">hide</div></div>
  </div>
```

The CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  padding: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hide {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}


.item:hover .hide {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

[Here is my codepen](https://codepen.io/Liskari/pen/yLjepRr)

I tried to expand the width from the hide element, but that doesn't work

```
.hide {
    width: 100vw;
}
```

Is there a method to expand the hide elements width or something else, so the "hide" won't go away if the parent element isn't hovered?

Answer (score 0):

Just tweaked some of the code for you so that the layout worked better. Main issue looks to be in the last line of CSS I've added where you target to see if the `.hide` has a `hover` state triggered.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  padding: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}

.hide {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    pointer-events:none;
}


.item:hover > .hide, .item > .hide:hover {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events:all;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">item
       <div class="hide">hide1</div>
    </div>
   <div class="item">item <div class="hide">hide2</div></div>
   <div class="item">item <div class="hide">hide3</div></div>
   <div class="item">item <div class="hide">hide4</div></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The problem is that the hidden text need to be aligned left in fullscreen

Comment: Hey @Liskari - just edited answer - it now has the same layout you wanted. WE just needed to ignore pointer events when not hovered and then apply them when it is, that way the 4th hidden element won't mess with the hover.